# How to find out the size of used range in the variant ignoring the empty ones

Tags: excel, vba

Okay Now I have got another problem with variants while working on it. I have succefully copied one variant to other. Now how do I determine the size of the new variant

```
Var1 = Sheet7.Range("B2:E2721").Value  ' 1st variant
ReDim Var2(1 To UBound(Var, 1), 1 To UBound(Var, 2)) ' New variant
```

Ok after doing some calculations out of 2720 rows, I have copied 2020 rows into new variant and the other values from 2020 to 2720 are empty in the new variant . Now I have to know the size of new variant. I have tried these

```
ubound(var2,1) ' its giving the size as 2721 not as 2020
```

How can we find out the size of variant to the used range ignoring the empty one. because the size plays crucial part when we  perform operations during loop or creating a another variant based on the other variant. and cant we define a variant without mentioning its dimensions? I Need to do split operation and add them to a variant, If that is the case I dont know how many split operations are performed and how many variables are taken out sometimes 20 or 40 , this should be copied to variant so we need a variant which is dynamic or something that can be resized

Comment: `after doing some calculations out of 2720 rows, I have copied 2020 rows into new variant` -- can't you just keep track of this number as you are copying, it will makes things much easier for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per jonsca's comment if you know how many records have been written or manipulated (2020) then you can cut the array from the 2721 record size at the end

The trick here is that you can't redim the first dimension of an array and preserve the existing data so we need a three stage workaround

1. Create the second array with a horizontal size equal to the vertical size of array 1, and  a vertical size equal to the horizonatl size of array 1 (so rather than 2720 rows by 4 columns we use 4 rows by 2720 columns)
2. Cut the columns from 2720 to 2020 at code end and preserve the written records
3. Dump the second array back to Excel but use Transpose to turn the 4 rows by 2020 columns into 2020 rows * 4 columns

Sample below (dumps to B2:E2021 on your second sheet)

```
Sub VarExample2()
Dim Var1()
Dim Var2()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Dim lngrow As Long
Var1 = ws1.Range("B2:E2721").Value2
'make our second array with columns equal to rows in the first, rows equal to columns
ReDim Var2(1 To UBound(Var1, 2), 1 To UBound(Var1, 1))
'Put some data in the second array, but not all 2720 records
For lngrow = 1 To 2020
Var2(1, lngrow) = lngrow & " apple up on top"
Var2(2, lngrow) = lngrow & " apple up on top next to the other one"
Next lngrow
'Cut the second array from 2720 columns to 2020
ReDim Preserve Var2(1 To UBound(Var1, 2), 1 To lngrow)
'Rotate the data from columns/rows into rows/columns in Excel
ws2.[b2].Resize(lngrow, UBound(Var2, 1)) = Application.Transpose(Var2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to leave the `var2` array intact and, when traversing it, just stop at index 2020 (don't continue to `UBound(var2,1)`=2721). Some may think this isn't very clean. In my opinion, anything else isn't worth the effort.

Comment: As per my post and from Microsoft help [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx , _"Preserve, Optional. Modifier used to preserve the data in the existing array when you change the size of only the **last** dimension."_